# How to change the datepicker current date text color?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, datepicker, uidatepicker

Since using datepicker with a dark background color, I set its textColor to white. All the date text shows what I want except the current date. If today is 7/23/2015, its text will be black but not white.

I tried and found no solution, anyone can help?

Current date text color

[image: current date text color]

Not current date text color:

[image: not current date text color]

Comment: put the picker into another **UIView**

Comment: You meant adding one more UIView with brighter background color? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize date picker at the same time write the below code or if you had taken datePicker from IBOutlet write it in viewDidLoad `[yourDatePicker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];`